# CakePHP Folder structure - what this is the use of libs folder?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

CakePHP APP folder contains following folders:

```
    - config
     - controllers
     - libs
     - locale
     - models
     - plugins
     - tmp  
     - vendors
     - webroot
```

what this is the use of libs folder ? what type of files can put inside that and use.. can any one give a example for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual entry : http://book.cakephp.org/view/899/CakePHP-Folder-Structure

> Contains 1st party libraries that do
>   not come from 3rd parties or external
>   vendors. This allows you to separate
>   your organization's internal libraries
>   from vendor libraries

So this would be any internal organization specific libraries that you use in your code as opposed to third party libraries (e.g. - thumbnail generators and the like)

Comment: In addition to app/vendors a new app/libs directory has been added. This directory can also be part of plugins, located at $plugin/libs. Libs directories are intended to contain 1st party libraries that do not come from 3rd parties or external vendors. This allows you to separate your organization's internal libraries from vendor libraries. App::import() has also been updated to import from libs directories.